# Decode base64 encoded file and print results to the console

Tags: python, base64

So I have a file that I have already encoded with base64, now I want to decode it back but instead of creating another file, I want to decode it in the console and print the results to screen. How to do that?

encoded file string = `MUhRRy1ITVRELU0zWDItNlcxSA==`

FYI:
this would mean first opening the file in console, then decoding the give string

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm overlooking something, this is as simple as reading in your encoded string and then calling the standard library's [`base64.b64decode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode) function on it.

Something like:

```
with open(path_to_encoded_file) as encoded_file:
    print base64.b64decode(encoded_file.read().strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [base64.decode](http://docs.python.org/2/library/base64#base64.decode), set `sys.stdout` (`sys.stdout.buffer.raw` in python 3.x) as output.

```
import sys
import base64

with open('filepath') as f:
    base64.decode(f, sys.stdout)
```